# Swap data after index for two lists c# linq

Tags: c#, linq, list

So I have two lists of bytes and I want to swap their data after a given index.

So I have these two lists

---

----0---1-----2-----3---- Index

#### **** #### #### -ListA

#### #### **** #### **** -ListB

and I want to say that if the index is 2 swap data like this

#### **** **** #### ****

#### #### #### ####

---

I'm not too familiar with linq, maybe there is a quick way to do this with it.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done without `Linq`.  Using `List.GetRange()`, `List.RemoveRange()`, & `List.AddRange()` you can perform the swap you are looking for, and is quick.

```
List<string> listA = new List<string>
{
    "####", 
    "****", 
    "####", 
    "####"
};

List<string> listB = new List<string>
{
    "####",
    "####",
    "****",
    "####",
    "****"
};

Console.WriteLine("Before: ");
Console.WriteLine("List A: {0}", String.Join(", ", listA));
Console.WriteLine("List B: {0}", String.Join(", ", listB));
Console.WriteLine();

SwapAfterIndex(listA, listB, 2);

Console.WriteLine("After: ");
Console.WriteLine("List A: {0}", String.Join(", ", listA));
Console.WriteLine("List B: {0}", String.Join(", ", listB));
```

`SwapAfterIndex()` looks like:

```
public static void SwapAfterIndex(List<string> listA, List<string> listB, int index)
{
    if (index < 0)
    {
        return;
    }

    List<string> temp = null;
    if (index < listA.Count)
    {
        temp = listA.GetRange(index, listA.Count - index);
        listA.RemoveRange(index, listA.Count - index);
    }

    if (index < listB.Count)
    {
        listA.AddRange(listB.GetRange(index, listB.Count - index));
        listB.RemoveRange(index, listB.Count - index);
    }

    if (temp != null)
    {
        listB.AddRange(temp);
    }
}
```

Results:

```
Before:
List A: ####, ****, ####, ####
List B: ####, ####, ****, ####, ****

After:
List A: ####, ****, ****, ####, ****
List B: ####, ####, ####, ####
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not think there is swap method for 2 List. You can acheive the same functionality using following code.

```
public static void Swap2List(List<byte> firstList, List<byte> secondList, int index)
  {
       // TODO : Error handling not done.  
        for(int i = index; i < firstList.Length ; i++)
       {
         var temp = firstList[i];
         firstList[index] = secondList[i];
         secondList[i] = temp;
       }
    }
```

Comment: I think you may have misunderstood the question - the OP wants all of the list to be swapped after the given index, not just the one element :).

Comment: As soon as you say, 'this should work", you should have tested your code and prove it to yourself first.  What happens if the index is less than zero, or if the index exceeds the size of one List but not the other?

Comment: I understand your point, This code is posted to demonstrate a possible solution, not to provide a copy - paste code.

Comment: But the solution you present isn't possible if the firstList has 5 elements (Indexes 0 - 4), and second list has 2 elements (Indexes 0 - 1). and your index is 3.  Your possible solution will throw IndexOutOfBoundsException.

Comment: Yes, as i mentioned previously, this code shows "what can be done as a solution" and is not supposed to exact "copy - paste" code